# Sending faxes in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fax

I build an app in RoR which is on heroku. And I want to send a fax every time an order is taking place. What will be the best option for me?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [InterFAX](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev) or [eFaxCorporate](http://www.efaxcorporate.com/). I don't think any of these APIs come pre-integrated with Heroku though. The use of InterFAX from a Ruby environment is documented on this [book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9781847193933).